# How much is the upper limit of video capacity when we use Video Editing?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I tried to edit about a 4.2GB-mp4-video, but Blender said "File A could not be loaded." The video length was almost 3 hours.
On the other hand, when I tried to load the only first 1 minute of the beginning,
Blender succeeded to load it and to display the sequences.

I think Blender may have the upper limit of movie capacity.
Can anyone tell me how much capacity Blender accepts?

Comment: depending on your operating system you could also open the task manager and change to the performance manager tab. Then load up Blender and start loading in the video clip. Have a look at the memory usage. If it goes towards 100% and then Blender crashes, it could indeed be a memory issue...

Answer (score 1):

Blender has the frame number limit.

[Working Limits : Time](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/limits.html#time)

> "The maximum number of frames for each scene is currently 1,048,574,
>   and allows for continuous shots for durations of:
>
> 24 fps:   12 hours, 8 seconds.
>
> 25 fps:   11 hours, 39 seconds.
>
> 30 fps:   9 hours, 42 seconds.
>
> 60 fps:   4 hours, 51 seconds."

But in your case this could be insufficient RAM as well.